# Include static HTML page under content of a drupal basic page. Can i make a block and include the static page?

Tags: jquery, html, drupal, drupal-7

Sorry guys i am a newbie to drupal, i have an existing basic page on drupal but i need to include static html with jquery underneath that content, can i use a block this way ? to Make this possible and how ?

Comment: $('.classToLoadFileInto').load('path/to/file.html');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, you can use block**. You can define a new region below the content **or** you can assign the html block in the content area itself. The block position can be assigned in admin->structure->blocks.